# If I pass an array of multiple stylesheet objects to a react native view, will it deprive me of stylesheet optimizations provided by React-native?

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

As per https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet,
React-native provides, some optimizations if we create styles form stylesheet.

It also says that if we flatten stylesheet, we wont get those benefits.

But what if we do not flatten the stylesheet and instead use multiple styles ? will we get those optimizations ?

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigBlue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});




<Text style={[styles.red, styles.bigBlue]}>{"red, then bigBlue"}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search react-native core code itself, you'd find more than 50 usages of the array usage.

[image]

Also you can find that usage as first-class citizen, with no notes or warnings whatsoever.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is no longer the case (at least regarding the docs part)